# How to handle having more than 100 connection to firebase in android app?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I was looking into different price plans for Firebase and I got two questions
1 - what is the technical difference between Free plan and Spark?
2 - How to handle having more than 100 connections?
Assuming at one point I have 101 users are trying to connect to Firebase, so one of them will fail.
How to handle this to try again later?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the Free and Spark plans are that the Spark plan lets use use a custom domain for Firebase Hosting.

But for managing over 100 connections, you'll have to upgrade to at least the Candle plan. This is one of the limitations of the Free and Spark tier.

The only thing you can do to manage the connections yourself is to disconnect users with `Firebase.goOffline()`. Which doesn't really do much for you.

Comment: If this answer works for you can you please mark it as resolved? It's good to keep the unanswered queue clean.